# Web Api returns status code 500 at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, runtime-error

I have a problem with my web api developed in asp.net core.
When I call them in POST I get the following error:

> ebbtelemetrywebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/events:1 Failed to load resource: >the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

The controller function il the following :

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EventsController : ControllerBase
    {
      [HttpPost]
      public async Task<IEnumerable<CosmosDBEvents>> 
      GetAsync(EventsGetTwoParamsDto dto)
      {
         try
            {
                switch(dto.Action2)
                {
                    case "Index":
                    case "Pagina5":
                        const string VERIFICATION_CODE = "where doc.deviceId = \"{0}\"";
                        var content = string.Format(VERIFICATION_CODE,dto.DeviceIdorId);

                        var items = await DocumentDBRepository<CosmosDBEvents>.GetItemsAsync(content);

                        if (items == null || items.Count() == 0)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                        MessagesController messageController = new MessagesController(_context);
                        EventsTypeDescriptionsController eventController = new EventsTypeDescriptionsController(_context);

                        int codice_evento;
                        string cultura;

                        foreach (var item in items)
                        {
                            codice_evento = Convert.ToInt32(item.eventId);
                            cultura = GetCulture();
                            item.decodifica_evento = messageController.GetMessageWithCulture(codice_evento, cultura);
                            item.descrizione_evento = eventController.GetDetail(codice_evento);
                        }
                        return (items);
                    case "BottoneLedOff":
                        content = string.Format(VERIFICATION_CODE, dto.DeviceIdorId);

                        items = await DocumentDBRepository<CosmosDBEvents>.GetItemsAsync(content);

                        if (items == null || items.Count() == 0)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                        items = (from item in items
                                 orderby item.startTS descending
                                 select item).Take(1);

                        var service = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(AppSettings.KeyIoT);
                        var methodInvocation = new CloudToDeviceMethod("GetData") { ResponseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200) };
                        var response = await service.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync(dto.DeviceIdorId, methodInvocation);

                        CosmosDBTelemetry realtime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CosmosDBTelemetry>(response.GetPayloadAsJson());

                        if(realtime.severity<90)
                        {
                            ((List<CosmosDBEvents>)items)[0].BLedAcceso = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            ((List<CosmosDBEvents>)items)[0].BLedAcceso = false;
                        }

                        return (items);
                    case "Dettagli":
                        // in questo caso il deviceid è l'id dell'evento eventId
                        if (dto.DeviceIdorId == null)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }

                        items = await DocumentDBRepository<CosmosDBEvents>.GetItemAsync(dto.DeviceIdorId);
                        var events = items.FirstOrDefault();


                        codice_evento = Convert.ToInt32(events.eventId);
                        cultura = GetCulture();


                        messageController = new MessagesController(_context);
                        events.decodifica_evento = messageController.GetMessageWithCulture(codice_evento, cultura);

                        eventController = new EventsTypeDescriptionsController(_context);
                        events.descrizione_evento = eventController.GetDetail(codice_evento);

                        if (events == null)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                        //ritorno una lista di un elemento
                        List<CosmosDBEvents> toRet = new List<CosmosDBEvents>
                        {
                            events
                        };
                        return (toRet);
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
   }
```

The dto class is declared as following :

```cs
    public class EventsGetTwoParamsDto
    {
        public string DeviceIdorId { get; set; }
        public string Action2 { get; set; }
    }
```

The AJAX call is the following :

```js
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: ENV.apiUrl+'/events',
        data: JSON.stringify({ DeviceIdorId: ENV.deviceId, Action2: 
    "Pagina5"}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("RISPOSTA", data);
        }
      });
```

I got the following exception :

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

I take a look to [AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795673/ambiguousactionexception-multiple-actions-matched-the-following-actions-matche)
but my case is a bit different. 
In my controller I have two GetAsync methods one that takes two parameters and one that takes three parameters. I believe this is the origin of the problem. In the post you mentioned you there is no such case and above all the case of POST methods.

Here it is the controller class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EventsController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly TelemetryWebContext _context;

    public EventsController(TelemetryWebContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CosmosDBEvents>> GetAsync([FromBody]EventsGetTwoParamsDto dto)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CosmosDBEvents>> GetAsync([FromBody]EventsGetThreeParamsDto dto)
    {
    }

    private string GetCulture() => "en-GB";
  }
```

Can sameone help me?

Comment: It would be helpul to see the content of your `GetAsync` method.

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: That's a huge code. Look at the stacktrace.

Comment: Done, but if I put a breakpoint in the switch line, it never stops.

Comment: You should run it on local machine in debug mode

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `switch(dto.Action2)` and check if dto is null
Or better, place a breakpoint at `throw ex;` and read the `Message` and `StackTrace` of the exception.

Comment: Yes I run it in a local machine in debug mode but it never stop in the breakpoint.

Comment: So, it means that you don't call this action. Is the breakpoint full red circle or red with white center? Is this question "How to debug my application"?

Comment: NO "{" at method beginning?

Comment: I added the class declaration. I confirm that when I do the call it never stop in the breakpoint

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795673/ambiguousactionexception-multiple-actions-matched-the-following-actions-matche

Comment: In my controller I have two GetAsync methods one that takes two parameters and one that takes three parameters. I believe this is the origin of the problem. In the post you mentioned you there is no such case and above all the case of POST methods.

Comment: @SimoneSpagna it seems that there is another action method that has the same route as "api/events" with POST HTTP method.

Comment: @CodeNotFound: it's probably the other method that takes three parameters. how do i differentiate them?

Comment: @SimoneSpagna shwo us that action please.

Comment: @CodeNotFound: Look at the post , Simone

Comment: @SimoneSpagna give one of them a new URL segment by using the HttpPost overload.

Comment: @CodeNotFOund: ForExample [HttpPost("xyz")] ?

Comment: @SimoneSpagna exactly.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I solved. Write the answer and I mark it. Vote also my post. Thanks a lot. Ciao.

Comment: You can answer yourself and accept it as The correct answer ;-)

Comment: @CodeNotFound : dome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem giving to the second method of the controller a new URL segment by using the `HttpPost` overload.

For example

```
[HttpPost("xyz")]
```

I thank CodeNotFound for the help he gave me.